# Android Google Play Billing (v5) : After purchasing new subscription, previous subscription won't stopping, it getting auto renew

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

I have a monthly subscription running already and then I purchased a yearly subscription what should happen to my previous subscription ideally, currently it not getting canceled (I can cancel manually only using the Play Store app) and after the billing period is over, it getting auto renew and charges again.

Also, please suggest code snippet or idea in order to update the current subscription instead buying other plan as new purchase so that it remains as one subscription instead of creating two subscriptions i.e old one (monthly) and second one (yearly)

I searched other related posts regarding this but nothing helpful was found. kindly help with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using different entitlements (rather than different base plans within the same entitlement), you should specify that you want to change the subscription instead of making an additional purchase. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#allow-users-change).

So, your `BillingFlowParams` should look like this:

```
BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
    .setProductDetailsParamsList(...)
    .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(...)
    .build()
```

Alternatively, you can create multiple base plans (e.g., monthly, yearly) within the same entitlement. This way, you won't need to specify cross-grade logic in your code unless the default logic from Google doesn't meet your requirements.